# Template dependent typename

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
struct bar
{
  template <typename U>
  void fun0() const {}
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  void
  fun1(const bar& d)
  {
    // (1) KO
    fun2(d).fun0<int>();
    // (2) OK
    fun2(d).template fun0<int>();
    // (3) OK        
    d.fun0<int>();
  }

  bar
  fun2(const bar& d)
  {
    return d;
  }
};
```

Lines (2) and (3) compile, but (1) fails with:

```
error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'fun0' as a dependent template name
    fun2(d).fun0<int>();

            ^
            template
```

(As expected, if `foo` is no longer a template struct, (1) compiles as well)

Why is `bar::fun0` a dependent template name here? `bar` doesn't depend on the template parameter `T` of `foo`.

Edit:

Clearly, `bar::fun2` is responsible for the ambiguity that the `.template` deal with. For instance, let's add the 2 following free functions:

```
bar
fun3(const bar& d)
{
  return d;
}

template <typename T>
T
fun4(const T& d)
{
  return d;
}
```

`fun3(d).fun0<int>()` and `fun4(d).fun0<int>()`) also compile in the context of `foo::fun1`. So the ambiguity is caused by the template parameter of `foo`.

Why is `fun2(d).fun0<int>()` not parsed as a call to a member function template?

Comment: Because you might specialize `fun2` to return something other than `bar`.

Comment: @AlanStokes How exactly would you specialise `fun2` in a way that does allows the return type to be changed, yet still keeps the `fun1` around?

Comment: @AlanStokes You can only specialise `fun2` to return a covariant type (so it must be derived from `bar`), so the covariant type is guaranteed to have the same functionality (i.e. it must have a `template <typename> void fun0() const` function). So it will always return a type that is actually a `bar`

Comment: @texasflood Citation needed.

Comment: @hvd Return a `baz` that also has a `fun0` member

Comment: @AlanStokes You can't return a `baz`. `fun2` is already declared as returning `bar`. You need to specialise the whole template, not just the member, to allow the return type to be different, and when specialising the whole template, `fun1` won't be kept around.

Comment: @hvd Ah, fair point.

Comment: @AlanStokes §10.3.7 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf). It's such a basic rule of OOP, I didn't think a citation was needed.

Comment: That applies to overrides of virtual functions, and isn't relevant here.

Comment: Funny thing: I've discovered this case as a probable [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-15139) in Resharper C++, but developers decided that it's a bug in clang/gcc and I had no counterargument at that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this comes down to the rules in section `14.6.2` of the standard. Basically, I think the rules err on the side of caution in requiring you to use `template` and `typename` -- once you form an expression which might potentially be dependent, sometimes it will be declared so according to the rules, even though a human can plainly see that it isn't actually dependent. Then, there is a general rule `14.6.2.2.1` which states

> Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent.

What I think is happening is that the expression `fun2(d)` is declared to be type-dependent by the rules, *even though* that type is in fact the same in every instantiation of this (primary) template, as you and I can see -- this is why it's surprising that `template` is required.

Under `14.6.2.1.4` in the C++11 (or C++14) standard,

> A name is a *dependent member of the current instantiation* if it is a member of the current instantiation
>   that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation.

That means, the name `fun2` is a *dependent name*, even though `fun2` does not refer to `T` or anything that explicitly depends on `T`.

Thus when we consider the expression you gave `fun2(d).fun0<int>()`, and consider the "member access subexpression", that is, `fun2(d)` **`.`** `fun0<int>` -- intuitively we want to say that this is not dependent, as `fun2(d)` is always of type `bar` and `fun0<int>` doesn't depend on `T` either. There is rule `14.6.2.2.5` which states

> A class member access expression (5.2.5) is type-dependent if the expression refers to a member of the current
>   instantiation and the type of the referenced member is dependent, or the class member access expression
>   refers to a member of an unknown specialization.

Neither of these conditions applies literally, since `bar` is not the same type as the current instantiation (`foo<T>`), and neither is `fun0<int>` a member of an unknown specialization of the `foo` template. This is why the expression `d.fun0<int>()` is well-formed.

However, note clearly that this rule `14.6.2.2.5` comes after `14.6.2.2.1` which sets up the meaning of this entire section:

> Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent.

Thus if any subexpression, such as `fun2`, is formally "type-dependent", it poisons the entire expression, and causes similar rules to apply as if we were looking up members of template parameters or unknown specializations, etc. etc.

Specifically, the `type-dependent` condition means that you need the `template` prefix, because of rule 14.2.4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postfix-expression or after a
>   nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object expression of the postfix-expression is type-dependent
>   or the nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of
>   the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template.
>   Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.
>
> Example:

```
struct X {
  template<std::size_t> X* alloc();
  template<std::size_t> static X* adjust();
};
template<class T> void f(T* p) {
  T* p1 = p->alloc<200>();          // ill-formed: < means less than
  T* p2 = p->template alloc<200>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
  T::adjust<100>();                 // ill-formed: < means less than
  T::template adjust<100>();        // OK: < starts template argument list
}
```

> — end example ]

Now very concretely:

1. By [14.2.4], in the postfix expression `fun2(d)` `.` `fun0<int>`, if the object expression `fun2(d)` is *type-dependent*, then you have to use `template` prefix to call the member template.
2. Under [14.6.2.2.1], if `fun2` is *type-dependent* then that forces `fun2(d)` to be also.
3. And under [14.6.2.1.4], since `fun2` when looked up refers to a member of the `foo` class template, that alone is enough to make it a *dependent member of the current instantiation*.

I don't have a totally clear argument from any of the rules that if a name refers to a *dependent member of the current instantiation*, then that implies that the expression corresponding to the name is `type-dependent`... and I have searched a few times now.

However, this viewpoint is advocated in @Johannes Schaub - litb's [highly up-voted (but simplified, and non-normative) exposition of the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords):

> **Dependent names**
>
> The Standard is a bit unclear about what exactly is a dependent name. On a simple read (you know, the principle of least surprise), all it defines as a dependent name is the special case for function names below. But since clearly T::x also needs to be looked up in the instantiation context, it also needs to be a dependent name (fortunately, as of mid C++14 the committee has started to look into how to fix this confusing definition).
>
> To avoid this problem, I have resorted to a simple interpretation of the Standard text. Of all the constructs that denote dependent types or expressions, a subset of them represent names. Those names are therefore "dependent names". A name can take different forms - the Standard says:
>
> A name is a use of an identifier (2.11), operator-function-id (13.5), conversion-function-id (12.3.2), or template-id (14.2) that denotes an entity or label (6.6.4, 6.1)
>
> An identifier is just a plain sequence of characters / digits, while the next two are the operator + and operator type form. The last form is template-name . All these are names, and by conventional use in the Standard, a name can also include qualifiers that say what namespace or class a name should be looked up in.

Would be great to get a more concrete explanation of that last part.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. So it seems it all boils down to a "too broad" definition of dependent names in the C++ standard?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to look at it. Whether it's a "defect" is a separate issue -- the fact is that the C++ grammar is ambiguous, and writing a performant and correct parser is difficult. Requiring `template` in cases like this may allow a parser to be written which is faster and uses less memory. Later the compiler knows the type of `fun2(d)`, but at the parser stage, it's just trying to figure out if in `fun0<int>` the `<` is a comparison operator or the start of a template parameter list -- at the time that `template` and `typename` are relevant it knows barely anything about your program.

Comment: Lowering strain on the parser is sure nice but adding pressure on the programmer who have to think and figure out why them has to put `template` in such cases could turn out to be net negative after all. Well maybe if only all the compilers could give nice error messages like clang in such case, it wouldn't matter that much.